# ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe2

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-storage, rsync, gsutil, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use Rync to copy files from a server to the Google Cloud storage for public CDN use. I have been able to copy most of the files, however, the one directory doesn't want to copy. I think it might have reached the limit of files I can rsync. This is the error, can someone please confirm?

I am using the Google Cloud Platform.

[root@plesk-test01 logs]# gsutil -m rsync -r -d /var/www/vhosts/path-to-site/wp-content/uploads/ gs://path-to-bucket/wp-content/uploads/

WARNING: gsutil rsync uses hashes when modification time is not available at
both the source and destination. Your crcmod installation isn't using the
module's C extension, so checksumming will run very slowly. If this is your
first rsync since updating gsutil, this rsync can take significantly longer than
usual. For help installing the extension, please see "gsutil help crcmod".

Building synchronization state...
Caught non-retryable exception while listing file:///var/www/vhosts/path-to-site/wp-content/uploads/: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe2' in position 121: ordinal not in range(128)
CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync
[root@plesk-test01 logs]#

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, found the solution.

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL=
```

This fixed the problem.

Comment: For posterity, the documentation about [unicode interoperability issues is here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/Filenameencodingandinteroperabilityproblems).